# Getting properties/parameters from page level

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I wonder if I can get the parameters and/or properties of an xpage or custom control programmatically.

```
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" id="layout">

<xp:this.properties>
    <xp:parameter name="testcc.xsp" value="Test 1"></xp:parameter>
    <xp:parameter name="index.xsp" value="Main"></xp:parameter>
</xp:this.properties>
...
```

How can I access this parameter list to use it e.g. in a repeat control?

**EDIT**
You both are right, thank you! But this works only on a page, not in a custom control.

**EDIT**

You both are great :-)

BUT: I should revise my question:
I have a custom control where I defined the properties. Within the SAMe custom control I want to access these properties in a repeat control.

Both your answers seem to assume that the access to these properties is from the view (page) level, right?

I tested Svens way - this works if I access the props in the CC from the page level.

**EDIT**

So this is the code of the CC:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">

<xp:this.properties>
    <xp:parameter name="param" value="val"></xp:parameter>
</xp:this.properties>

<xp:label value="#{javascript:facesContext.getProperty('param')}"
    id="label1">
</xp:label>

</xp:view>
```

As you can see I just want to access the property within the CC itselt, not from the page level.

Comment: What do you mean with "works not in a custom control"? Accessing the properties? Or do you set the properties in a custom control?

Comment: I mean accessing the properties within the CC, defined in the CC

Comment: No, this should work in both ways. Could you please post more of your code? As often, my code works fine for me ;-)

Comment: I think you access the properties using compositeData.propertyName where propertyName is the name of the property passed through when the custom control is invoked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the properties by accessing *facesContext*:

```
facesContext.getProperty("index.xsp")
```

**EDIT:**

If you set the properties in a custom control, the properties are not added to the view root. The are set as attributes of the custom control (*com.ibm.xsp.component.UIIncludeComposite*).

To access them you first have to give your CC an Id:

```
<xc:ccProp id="myId" />
```

This allows you to access the custom control like a component with the *getComponent()* method and retrieve the attribute *properties* which contains the properties:

```
<xp:label id="labelProperty">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:
        var cc:com.ibm.xsp.component.UIIncludeComposite = getComponent("myId");
        var arrList:java.util.ArrayList = cc.getAttributes().get("properties");
        arrList.get(0).getName()}]]>
    </xp:this.value>
</xp:label>
```

**EDIT 2:**

You can access the CC (which is the parent of the label in this example) this way if you don't want to give your CC an ID:

*Code of the custom control:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">

    <xp:this.properties>
        <xp:parameter name="param" value="val"></xp:parameter>
    </xp:this.properties>

    <xp:label id="label1">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:
            this.parent.getAttributes().get("properties").get(0).getName()
       }]]></xp:this.value>
   </xp:label>

    <xp:label id="label2">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:
            this.parent.getAttributes().get("properties").get(0).getValue()
       }]]></xp:this.value>
   </xp:label>

</xp:view>
```

Hope this helps to clarify the issue.

Comment: Hmm this does not work for me, but no errors, just no value returned.
**EDIT**
This only works on an xpage, but not in a custom control.

Comment: @OliverBusse: This also worked for me in XPage as well as custom control.

Comment: @OliverBusse: Updated the answer with a second example.

Answer (score 1):

To get the property list you can use the `view.getProperties()`. It returns an object of `java.util.List` which you can use to loop through individual properties (which are objects of `com.ibm.xsp.complex.Parameter`). Below is the snippet.

```
var allProperties:java.util.List = view.getProperties();
for (var i=0 ; i<allProperties.size() ; i++) {
    var property:com.ibm.xsp.complex.Parameter = allProperties.get(i);

    // property.getName();
    // property.getValue();
}
```

If you want to put it in a repeat then you can bind it to `view.getProperties()` and then get its individual values. You code would then look something like this:

```
<xp:repeat rows="30" value="#{javascript:view.getProperties()}" var="property">
    <xp:text escape="true">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:property.getName() + " - " + property.getValue();}]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:text>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
</xp:repeat>
```

Comment: **EDIT**
This only works on an xpage, but not in a custom control.

Comment: @OliverBusse: This is weird! This works in my case. I put the `xp:repeat` in my custom control and it worked. I am using 8.5.3FP1 on local. Which version are you using?

Comment: I am using 8.5.3FP3, client & server.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got values that you want to use on the various parts of an Xpage, whether directly on the page, in a custom control, or in a repeat, I would recommend that you put the values into sessionScope variables. This allows you to change them easily as the user enters information on the Xpage.

For example, `sessionScope.PODocUNID = poDoc.getDocument().getUniversalID();` would put the UNID of the purchase order document that I'm working with into a sessionScope variable named PODocUNID. Then, you can pull up the value any time you want by simply referencing sessionScope.PODocUNID in your code.

Alternatively, you could use Russ Maher's current favorite toy, the Managed Bean (see his three-part video on Notes in 9, starting at: http://notesin9.com/index.php/2012/11/02/notesin9-084-sharing-managed-beans-in-xpages/ )