# <li class="active"> in function of page you're on

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, xpages, xpages-ssjs

On an xpage I have a navbar.
On this navbar you have the  which should show on which page you're on.
How can I calculate and put this class to the correct li

I tried the following which doesn't work :

```
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active">
                <xp:text escape="false" id="computedField1">
                    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:active = @RightBack(view.getPageName(),'/');
                     main ="<a href='product.xsp'>PRODUCTS</a>";
                     home ="<a href='home.xsp'>HOME</a>";
                     if (active =="product.xsp"){
                     return main
                     }
                     else {
                     return home
                     }}]]></xp:this.value>
                </xp:text>

            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">NEXT LINK</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">ANOTHER LINK</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

In fact I would like to calculate the class.
When I am on the HOME page the HOME link should get the class active.
When I am on the PRODUCTS page the HOME link should become a normal li and the products li should get the active class li.

How can I calculate the class ?

As far as I know there's no add class possibility in SSJS ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're able to compute properties for passthrough tags, though you can't use the "this." notation for them. For this kind of thing, I often do:

```
<li class="${view.pageName == '/home.xsp' ? 'active' : ''}">...</li>
<li class="${view.pageName == '/products.xsp' ? 'active' : ''}">...</li>
```

Comment: products is in fact a dropdown (class dropdown), so should become active (class dropdown active) when one of the links will be clicked under this dropdown. Any sollution for that to ?

Comment: in the oneUI world our "layout" custom control which is on each page has a custom "navPath" property. this gets fed to the "selection" property of the link nodes in the app layout control.  Works well and very flexible.  Maybe something similar could be done here with regex...

Comment: David's suggestion is good. The "real" answer I use is to write a renderer for the <xe:navigator/> control in the vein of Bootstrap4XPages - in the renderer, there are methods to check if any child is active. However, that's a PITA - the navigationPath/regex-matching route is much quicker. e.g.

    class="#{javascript: /^\/Posts\/.*$/.test(compositeData.navPath) ? 'active open' : ''}"

Comment: Jesse, is there a way to put an or statement in your exmample : li class="${view.pageName == '/home.xsp' ? etc This could be a sollution for me since I only have 2 pages under my dropdown.

Comment: I just have to add or before the ? and then I can put another pagename
It seems to work this way, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Marc - I wonder if this might work out for you.

In an XPage itself under all properties you can add Attributes to the page.  In theory these are similar to custom properties on a custom control.  So I'd think that maybe you could add an attribute called something like "selectedMenu". And give it a value of the name of the item you want highlighted.

then in the navbar custom control you add some code to get the attribute and then add the proper class to the navBar menu item that you want.

I've never used XPage attributes like this before but someone has at work.  I think Mike's used them to do a similar thing to what you're looking for actually.

I found another SO question that talks about how to access the properties.

[Getting properties/parameters from page level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15163351/getting-properties-parameters-from-page-level)

This might be a good way to go.